# Array of object, strange interating error

Tags: python

I wanted to create a simple graph class, where I store Nodes and each Node stores its neighbours.
But when I intrate over I only get `<class '__main__.Node'>`object back which I can access any methods of the Node class (like `__str__`).

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, Node_arr=None):
        self.name = None
        if Node_arr == None:
            Node_arr = []
        self.__Node_arr = Node_arr

    def add_vertex(self, node):
        #if node not in self.__Node_arr:
        self.__Node_arr.append(Node)

    def get_nachbarn(self):
        return self.__Node_arr

    def set_name(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Graph2(object):

    def __init__(self, n, Node_arr=None):
        if Node_arr == None:
            Node_arr = []
            for i in range(n):
                c1 = Node()
                c1.set_name(str(i))
                Node_arr.append(c1)

        self.__Node_arr = Node_arr

    def add_vertex(self, node):
        self.__Node_arr.append(node)

    def add_edge(self, edge1, edge2):       
        v1 = self.__Node_arr[edge1]
        v2 = self.__Node_arr[edge2]

        v1.add_vertex(v2)
        v2.add_vertex(v1)

    def __str__(self):
        res = ""

        for k in self.__Node_arr:
            res += "Kanten von "+str(k) + " nach\n"

            for j in k.get_nachbarn():
                res += str(j)+" "

            res += "\n"

        return res  

if __name__ == "__main__":  
    g = Graph2(5)
    g.add_edge(0,1)

    print(g)
```

Output is:

```
Kanten von 0 nach
<class '__main__.Node'>
Kanten von 1 nach
<class '__main__.Node'>
Kanten von 2 nach

Kanten von 3 nach

Kanten von 4 nach
```

But should be:

```
Kanten von 0 nach
1
Kanten von 1 nach
0
Kanten von 2 nach

Kanten von 3 nach

Kanten von 4 nach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Node(object):
    def add_vertex(self, node):
        #if node not in self.__Node_arr:
        self.__Node_arr.append(Node)
```

You are saving the class `Node`, not its instance `node`.